# How can I multiply two arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays, for example

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

I need to multiply them and create a third array `c` that will be like this

```
c = [3 * 1, 2 * 2, 1 * 3]
```

Which method is the best by speed? I need to do this for huge arrays, and time is important.

Comment: @shivam sorry, really same topic, thanks

Comment: Its alright. Glad you found what you were looking for :)

Comment: I've reopened the question, because the OP is not looking for the sum.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For future reference, have a look at [How to select correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125486/how-to-select-the-correct-answer-when-their-content-is-equal?lq=1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
a.zip(b).map{|x, y| x * y}
```

This works because [zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) combines the two arrays into a single array of two element arrays. i.e.:

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 3]
a.zip(b)
#=> [[3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Then you use [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to multiply the elements together. This is done by iterating through each two element array and multiplying one element by the other, with map returning the resulting array.

```
a.zip(b).map{|x, y| x * y}
#=> [3, 4, 3]
```

Comment: If your answer included some informative text you wouldn't have to pad it with a bunch of periods. An answer with only code may be the right answer, but it's never a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[[3,2,1],[1,2,3]].transpose.map {|a| a.inject(:*)}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  For future reference, have a look at [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
a.map.with_index{ |x, i| a[i]*b[i]}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid `x` as it is not used?.  For future reference, have a look at [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to multiply two arrays, we have to assume they are of same size.

Hence, below is a simple way to multiply them - it has O(n) time complexity. Other answers are also equally good, you can pick any one

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 3]

a.size.times.collect { |i| a[i] * b[i] }
#=> [3, 4, 3]
```

If time is really of the essence, then, you may want to use multiple threads.  A sample program demonstrating the concept is shown below.  You can build upon it based on your specific needs.

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
b = [1, 2, 3]

num_cores = 2 # This decides number of threads, ideally equal to number of cores
ary_size = a.size

# We need to collect result of each thread as separate sub-array.
# We will use result array-of-array so that order of result is preserved
results = Array.new(num_cores, [])

# Divide the array indexes into equal parts    
index_splits = (0...ary_size).each_slice(num_cores)

threads = []

# Process each sub-array in a thread of its own
index_splits.each_with_index do |ary, i| 
    threads << Thread.new do
      results[i] = ary.collect {|j| a[j] * b[j] } 
    end
end
threads.each {|t| t.join} 

p results.flatten
#=> [3,4,3]
```

Comment: Thanks to all, i will try to use multiple threads, maybe it really will work faster

Comment: There may be a bug in my sample code on threads, I am working on it.